# How to read a long Excel file using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to print out the number of duplicates per cell in a column. For example:

```
 Jan-06-12  = 6
 Fen-06-12  = 10
```

?   No idea how to do that..all I did was print out the whole column onto IDLE.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = r'GenieSales.xlsx', use_iterators = True)
count = 0
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Sheet1')
for column in ws.iter_rows(range_string =('I2:I51509')): # it brings a new method: iter_rows()
    for cell in column:
        print cell.internal_value


#print sheet_ranges['I2'].value # D18
#if sheet_ranges['I'].value == 'Jan-06-12':
#    print '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

`cell.internal_value` refers to the value stored by Excel. This is always either a string or a number. Dates are numbers based on a calendar with 1900-01-01 as the epoch. If you want to work with the values in Python just use the `cell.value` which will convert the Excel value to Python.

Comment: I get an error when using cell.value..AttributeError: 'RawCell' object has no attribute 'value'.  I think it is because of the ws.iter_rows function

Comment: Just upgrade to the latest version.